# Wordpress Development Workflow with Git

Tags: wordpress, git, workflow

I am looking to integrate version control into my Wordpress development workflow. I have experience with Git in rails application development, so that seemed like a good option. However, I haven't found any holistic information that pertains to my needs and is in my knowledge level.

I would like to be able to accomplish the following:

- develop site locally(I would only be touching the theme files for the most part, so I would want to look to the production environment for the rest of the files to avoid redundancy)
- have Wordpress look for theme information in my repository (most likely will be on Bitbucket, but am open to server hosting solutions)

I hope that I am describing this clear enough for someone to have insight. If not I am glad to go into more depth of my goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to "[WordPress + Composer + GIT](https://medium.com/@halles/wordpress-composer-git-1ccf29a9827a)"

It uses (in addition of Git) [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) (a dependencies managing tool for PHP), and [WordPress Packagist](https://wpackagist.org/) (a repositories site that automatically packages the plugins and themes available in WordPress site in the format required for working with composer)

That way, you keep a declarative approach where you declare ion a `composer.json` what you need: this is easier to version in a Git repo.